# Can the Wish spell be used to cast 8th-level or lower spells that are not on your spell list?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic, wish

I can't seem to find anything that contradicts this.

The description of the [*wish*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) spell says:

> The basic use of this spell is to duplicate any other spell of 8th level or lower. You don't need to meet any requirements in that spell, including costly components. The spell simply takes effect.

**Can I use *wish* to cast any spell available in the game, regardless of its availability on my spell list or whether I have it prepared?**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Wish can duplicate any other spell, even one not on your list

You've quoted the important part yourself:

> The basic use of this spell is to duplicate **any other spell** of 8th level or lower.

There are no qualifications or restrictions to this statement beyond what is said here. As long as it is 8th level or lower you can call any spell.

If there were any further restrictions it would say so in the spell description.